# Plotting on a geographical map the provenience of our patients

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, gis, r-sf

I am trying to put on a Italian geographical map a dot reporting the provenience ('provincia') of our patients. Ideally, the dot size should be proportional to the number of patients coming from that 'provincia'. An example of the list I would like to plot is the following.

```
MI  8319
CO  537
MB  436
VA  338
BG  310
PV  254
CR  244
NO  210
RM  189
CS  179
```

In the first column there is the 'provincia' code: MI (Milano), CO (Como), MB (Monza-Brianza), etc. In the second column there is the number of patients from that 'provincia'. So the output should be an Italian political map where the biggest dot is around the city of Milano (MI), the second biggest dot is near the city of Como (CO), the third one is around the city of Monza-Brianza (MB),etc.
 Is there any package that could do the plot I am looking for? I found a tool that could do the job here, but apparently they expect that I load the geographical coordinates in order to do the plot.

https://www.littlemissdata.com/blog/maps

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do what you want, but you probably need to know the coordinates for each province you want to plot. Try to search Eurostat for geos data and from there you can compute centroid for each polygon/province.

Comment: @jyr.Thanks. I tried to look for coordinates at the Eurostat website, but I couldn't spot the geos data. Do you have by any chance a more specific link?

Comment: try this link https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units there are nuts units and other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE ON INSET MAP**

This is an update following different suggestion on using inset maps, which I think it would be the best solution for yout question and comments:

```
library(sf)
library(cartography)


EU = st_read("~/R/mapslib/EUROSTAT/NUTS_RG_03M_2016_3035_LEVL_3.geojson")
IT = subset(EU, CNTR_CODE == "IT")
mydata <-
  structure(list(
    abbs = c("MI", "CO", "MB", "VA", "BG", "PV", "CR",
             "NO", "RM", "CS"),
    value = c(8319L, 537L, 436L, 338L, 310L, 254L,
              244L, 210L, 189L, 179L),
    nuts = c("ITC4C","ITC42","ITC4D","ITC41",
             "ITC46", "ITC48","ITC4A","ITC15",
             "ITI43","ITF61")
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -10L))

patients = merge(IT, mydata, by.x = "id", by.y = "nuts")

#Get breaks for map
br=getBreaks(patients$value)
#Delimit zone
#Based on NUTS1, Nortwest Italy
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
ghostLayer(IT[grep("ITC",IT$NUTS_ID),], bg="lightblue")
plot(st_geometry(EU), col="grey90", add=TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(IT), col = "#FEFEE9", border = "#646464", add=TRUE)
choroLayer(
  patients,
  var = "value",
  breaks = br,
  col = carto.pal(pal1 = "red.pal", n1 = length(br)-1),
  legend.pos = "topleft",
  legend.title.txt = "Total patients",
  add = TRUE,
  legend.frame = TRUE
)
labelLayer(patients,txt="abbs", halo=TRUE, overlap = FALSE)

#Inset
par(
  fig = c(0, 0.4, 0.01, 0.4),
  new = TRUE
)
inset=patients[patients$abbs %in% c("RM","CS"),]
ghostLayer(inset, bg="lightblue")
plot(st_geometry(EU), col="grey90", add=TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(IT), col = "#FEFEE9", border = "#646464", add=TRUE)
choroLayer(
  patients,
  var = "value",
  breaks = br,
  col = carto.pal(pal1 = "red.pal", n1 = length(br)-1),
  legend.pos = "n",
  add = TRUE
)
labelLayer(patients,txt="abbs", halo=TRUE, overlap = FALSE)
box(which = "figure", lwd = 1)
```

[image]

```
#RESTORE PLOT

par(fig=c(0,1,0,1))
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Following my comment on plotting labels, maybe with circles is not the best option for your map, given the concentration. I suggest you to use another kind of map for that, as chorolayer, I leveraged on https://stackoverflow.com/users/3304471/jazzurro for the `dataframe`.

```
    library(sf)
    library(cartography)

    EU = st_read("~/R/mapslib/EUROSTAT/NUTS_RG_03M_2016_3035_LEVL_3.geojson")
    IT = subset(EU, CNTR_CODE == "IT")
    mydata <-
      structure(list(
        abbs = c("MI", "CO", "MB", "VA", "BG", "PV", "CR",
                 "NO", "RM", "CS"),
        value = c(8319L, 537L, 436L, 338L, 310L, 254L,
                  244L, 210L, 189L, 179L),
        nuts = c("ITC4C","ITC42","ITC4D","ITC41",
                 "ITC46", "ITC48","ITC4A","ITC15",
                 "ITI43","ITF61")
      ),
      class = "data.frame",
      row.names = c(NA, -10L))

    patients = merge(IT, mydata, by.x = "id", by.y = "nuts")

    #Options1 - With circles
    par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
    plot(st_geometry(IT), col = "#FEFEE9", border = "#646464")
    propSymbolsLayer(
      x = patients,
      var = "value",
      col = carto.pal(pal1 = "red.pal", n1 = 6),
      legend.title.txt = "Total patients",
      add = TRUE
    )

    #Option 2 - Chorolayer with labels
    par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
    plot(st_geometry(IT), col = "#FEFEE9", border = "#646464")
    choroLayer(
      patients,
      var = "value",
      col = carto.pal(pal1 = "red.pal", n1 = 6),
      legend.title.txt = "Total patients",
      add = TRUE
    )
    #Create labels
    patients$label = paste(patients$abbs, patients$value, sep = " - ")
    labelLayer(
      patients,
      txt = "label",
      overlap = FALSE,
      halo = TRUE,
      show.lines = TRUE,
      )
```

[image: Options1]
[image: Options2]

Data from 
https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/distribution/v2/nuts/nuts-2016-files.html

Comment: Thanks. Your map looks prettier and more informative than the one provided earlier. Where can I get exactly the NUTS for each 'provincia' symbol?

Comment: I matched myself, but if you have a look to the data on the link there is a label that you can use. NUTS is the standardised European code for countries and regions, check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUTS_statistical_regions_of_Italy

Comment: Also, as @jazzurro suggested, a zoomed map would be better in your case, I can try to add a reprex (code) for you

Comment: I updated the answer with an example on inset map using base `plot`, more information about this technique on https://dieghernan.github.io/201911_QuickR/

Comment: Excellent!. Thank you. Now your answer looks better than the previous one. I changed the flag.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to handle your task. You have the abbreviations for Italian province. You want to use them to merge your data with polygon data. If you download Italy's polygons from GADM, you can obtain data that contain the abbreviations. Specifically, the column, `HASC_2` is the one. You need to merge your data with the polygon data. Then, you want to create another data set which contains centroid. You can draw a map with the two data sets.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(ggthemes)

# Get the sf file from https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html
# and import it in R.

mysf <- readRDS("gadm36_ITA_2_sf.rds")

# This is your data, which is called mydata.
mydata <- structure(list(abbs = c("MI", "CO", "MB", "VA", "BG", "PV", "CR", 
"NO", "RM", "CS"), value = c(8319L, 537L, 436L, 338L, 310L, 254L, 
244L, 210L, 189L, 179L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

   abbs value
1    MI  8319
2    CO   537
3    MB   436
4    VA   338
5    BG   310
6    PV   254
7    CR   244
8    NO   210
9    RM   189
10   CS   179

# Abbreviations are in HASC_2 in mysf. Manipulate strings so that
# I can join mydata with mysf with the abbreviations. I also get
# longitude and latitude with st_centroid(). This data set is for
# geom_point().

mysf2 <- mutate(mysf, HASC_2 = sub(x = HASC_2, pattern = "^IT.", replacement = "")) %>% 
         left_join(mydata, by = c("HASC_2" = "abbs")) %>% 
         mutate(lon = map_dbl(geometry, ~st_centroid(.x)[[1]]),
                lat = map_dbl(geometry, ~st_centroid(.x)[[2]]))

# Draw a map

ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = mysf) +
geom_point(data = mysf2, aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = value)) +
theme_map()
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Is there also a way I could read in (instead of typing) the file with the 'provincia' symbol plus the number of patients? Also, would it be possible to print the 'provincia' symbol near the dot? Please let me know if you prefer that I generate a new question for this. Thanks again for your help and assistance.

Comment: @Arturo If you want to add some images, you probably want to study the ggtext package. You said that you would want to plot the symbols near the dots. But I am not sure if this is a good way. If you have a map with entire Italy, you would not have enough space between dots; you would probably mess around your map. If you would create a zoomed map, that approach would work. I am off to bed now.

Comment: For labelling a map you can use `labelLayer`, included on `cartography`, http://riatelab.github.io/cartography/docs/reference/labelLayer.html